# MySQL/Python preemptive caching

Tags: python, mysql, orm, memcached

I run a web app that's written in python and uses mysql as our primary datastore.  We have a large table with tens of millions of rows on amazon RDS, and expect it to get 10x larger.  We run a lot of queries that select a few hundred random rows based on the primary key (like "select * from table where id IN (ids)" where id is primary key).  It's occasionally pretty slow, taking 30+ seconds.  Eventually we'll have to shard the table, but we've been thinking of trying to keep copies of the rows cached in memcache.  Before running the select query, we'd send a multi_get to memcache.  Given our workflow (we run a lot of updates), we'd only get a significant performance increase if we preemptively write changes to a row to the memcache version too.

I'm wondering if anyone has used a setup like this, and if there are ORMs that handle this nicely or other useful tools (like maybe pulling changes from the mysql binary log and sending them to memcache).  The riskiest part of this is if someone forgets to update or at least invalidate a row in memcache that they update on mysql.

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to comment more on your access patterns.  Are the id's used in the `WHERE IN(...)` clause somehow related (to where you get the same sets of id's requested frequently)?  Are you typically only referencing more recently added rows?  Are you using any sort of replication or clustering?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's relatively little overlap in the sets of ids in the WHERE clause.  Typically at least half of the ids are essentially uniformly random and were not added recently.  Replication is an option, but we'd prefer to optimize a single DB before moving to that.  We use amazon RDS, so clustering isn't an option.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of "transparent" caching in Django: https://github.com/mmalone/django-caching. 
However, I should warn you that caching this way can get very complex, very quickly.

If you have tens of millions of rows and your access pattern is often by row id, then you may want to consider a NoSQL solution. Since you are already on AWS, consider using either [DynamoDB](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb) or [SimpleDB](http://aws.amazon.com/simpledb).  Both offer fast and scalable key-value access.